# Regex.Match giving unexpected result

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have been using `Regex.Match` function to match two string using following code

```
bool contains = Regex.Match(highlightedText, searchText, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success;
```

Here this code working fine but if i set `highlightedText` as say 'Rajeev' and `searchText` set to '.' i.e dot. It still returns me `true`.

If i search for `.` in any string it gives me `true` wheather or not `highlightedText` contains '.' or not.

Why it is giving me false value ?

Comment: if you want match literal `.` use `[.]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex `"."` is any symbol. Your string contains any symbol? Yes.
Use `@"\."` (escape dot) for find string contains dot.

For simple search substring in a string use `string.IndexOf` like this:

```
string text = "some kind of text";

Console.WriteLine("'{0}' contains '{1}'? {2}", text, "some", text.IndexOf("some", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
Console.WriteLine("'{0}' contains '{1}'? {2}", text, "pleasure", text.IndexOf("pleasure", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

Result:

```
'some kind of text' contains 'some'? True
'some kind of text' contains 'pleasure'? False
```

Comment: is this is case for only '.' or with any other character also

Comment: @RajeevKumar Formatting problem. I have corrected it.

Comment: Yup, much simpler to use `IndexOf` if you don't want to use the regex behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The [dot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) matches every single character. To match the dot itself, use `"\."`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `searchText` is the actual regular expression, which has certain characters reserved for interpretation. These are typically referred to as metacharacters and can include:

- the backslash `\`
- the caret `^`
- the dollar sign `$`
- the period or dot `.`
- the vertical bar or pipe symbol `|`
- the question mark `?`
- the asterisk or star `*`
- the plus sign `+`
- the opening parenthesis `(`
- the closing parenthesis `)`
- the opening square bracket `[`
- the opening curly brace `{`.

  If you want to use any of these as literal characters in your search then you need to escape them by prefixing with a backslash... eg `\.`
  In your case, the `.` metacharacter is used as a wildcard to represent ANY single character.

Answer (score 1):

basically regex syntax,

```
Regex.Match(STRING, PATTERN, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

so your `searchText` param will be treated as the regex pattern, that's why you get `true` as return.

"`.`"   Matches any single character except a newline character

Other list of behavior 
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/46/c-regular-expressions-cheat-sheet

```
Regex.Match(highlightedText, @"\.", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success
```

This will be work for your case.